# How to add attribute/property to each record/object in an array? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I'm not sure if this is just a lacking of the Rails language, or if I am searching all the wrong things here on Stack Overflow, but I cannot find out how to add an attribute to each record in an array.

**Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:**

```
@news_stories.each do |individual_news_story|
  @user_for_record = User.where(:id => individual_news_story[:user_id]).pluck('name', 'profile_image_url');
  individual_news_story.attributes(:author_name) = @user_for_record[0][0]
  individual_news_story.attributes(:author_avatar) = @user_for_record[0][1]
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `NewsStory` model (or whatever its name is) has a `belongs_to` relationship to `User`, then you don't have to do any of this. You can access the attributes of the associated `User` directly:

```
@news_stories.each do |news_story|
  news_story.user.name  # gives you the name of the associated user
  news_story.user.profile_image_url  # same for the avatar
end
```

To avoid an [N+1 query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-n1-select-query-issue), you can preload the associated user record for every news story at once by using `includes` in the `NewsStory` query:

```
NewsStory.includes(:user)... # rest of the query
```

If you do this, you won't need the `@user_for_record` query — Rails will do the heavy lifting for you, and you could even see a performance improvement, thanks to not issuing a separate `pluck` query for every single news story in the collection.

**If you need to have those extra attributes there regardless:**

You can select them as extra attributes in your `NewsStory` query:

```
NewsStory.
  includes(:user).
  joins(:user).
  select([
    NewsStory.arel_table[Arel.star],
    User.arel_table[:name].as("author_name"),
    User.arel_table[:profile_image_url].as("author_avatar"),
  ]).
  where(...) # rest of the query
```

Comment: Thank you @Máté, I am now using the benefits of the assocation rather than doing the hard query. However I am still having trouble assigning these values as additional attributes/properties to the record/object. I should have stated this in the original question, but these properties I am attempting to add are not inherent in the model. I am merely adding them to form a desired API response. Do you know if this is possible or must they be attributes in the model from the start?

Comment: Updated my answer. Though if you want to control how your API response looks, you should use serializers instead of contorting your ActiveRecord queries.

Comment: Thank you @Máté, really appreciate both the updated answer and the serializer recommendation. Going to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to cache the name and avatar of the user on the NewsStory model, in which case, what you want is this:

```
@news_stories.each do |individual_news_story|
  user_for_record = User.find(individual_news_story.user_id)

  individual_news_story.author_name = user_for_record.name
  individual_news_story.author_avatar = user_for_record.profile_image_url
end
```

A couple of notes.

1. I've used `find` instead of `where`. `find` returns a single record identified by it's primary key (id); where returns an array of records. There are definitely more efficient ways to do this -- [eager-loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), for one -- but since you're just starting out, I think it's more important to learn the basics before you dig into the advanced stuff to make things more performant.
2. I've gotten rid of the `pluck` call, because here again, you're just learning and `pluck` is a performance optimization useful when you're working with large amounts of data, and if that's what you're doing then activerecord has a [batch api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) you should look into.
3. I've changed `@user_for_record` to `user_for_record`. The `@` denote instance variables in ruby. Instance variables are shared and accessible from any instance method in an instance of a class. In this case, all you need is a local variable.